# Is there a purely CSS way to make something happen when you click (not click and hold) an element?

Tags: html, css

I think the best example of what I am thinking of would be like you click on an image and it changes the filter and that filter stays even if you're not holding down on the image.

At first I thought maybe I could use the :active pseudo-class on an image to make it grayscale upon click as a test however it didn't work. Then I tried making the image a link and doing

```css
a:visited {
    filter:  grayscale(100%);
}
```

however, it did not work.

Comment: `:active` requires the mouse button down and `:visited` only permits a limited range of properties to apply.

Comment: Please don't add meta-commentary like asking questions about votes to your question. The question should stay focused on you actual question. You can use [meta] to ask questions about your question, but it carries the risk of bringing more attention to your question.

Comment: Damn. Is there anyway to make it so if I click an element it changes something permanently until the page is refreshed using purely css/html?

Comment: You could wrap the element in a `label` for an `<input type="checkbox">` and style it using `:checked`

Comment: FWIW, please note that any scenario in which you sort of "hack" HTML to use non-semantic elements to achieve some behavior might result in deleterious effects to accessibility and SEO.  Depending on what you're doing this may or not be the case, but it seems like a potential outcome.

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderNied's comment; be wary of using checkboxes in this manner.  Consider carefully whether you need the behavior described or if there's a "good enough" behavior that is close enough to make it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that by pure CSS, but you can use a hidden checkbox to manipulate the image.

```css
input.hidden {
  display: none;
}

label > img {
  transition: filter 300ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label > img {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="doggy" class="hidden" type="checkbox">
  <label for="doggy"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for a clever solution, but as I pointed out in a previous comment, it is worth noting for anyone looking to implement this solution that it will have deleterious affects on accessibility and potentially SEO if you don't take additional steps to prevent assistive technologies from reporting these things as form inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Play with `transition` and you can simulate it:

```css
img {
  transition: 0s 9999s filter; /* a big delay on mouseout so it take a lot of time to change */
  cursor: pointer;
}

img:active {
  transition: 0s filter; /* instant change on click */
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/125/200/200">
```